# How to add a Bootstrap icon to an XPage Button or Link core control?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I've been trying to adopt Twitter Bootstrap for my XPages applications. So far, I have mainly experimented with CSS.

One of the things I really like is the easy way to decorate buttons (i.e. add icon to a button), using the following syntax:

```
<button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Approve</button>
```

The decoration is added using the `<i>` tag inside of the `<button>` tag. And here lies the problem. When using the button core control, the `<i>` tag would need to go inside the `value` attribute. And that, of course, is not working.

I could fix this by modifying the CSS, but that is not the course that I want to pursue.

The solution is to "inject" the `<i>` tag after the button control is rendered. I haven't had success with server side script, but I managed to do it with Dojo, like this:

```
<xp:button id="button1" styleClass="btn" value="Approve">
</xp:button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var decorate = function() {
    e = dojo.query("[id$='button1']")[0];
    e.innerHTML = '<i class="icon-ok"></i> Aprove';
  }    

  dojo.addOnLoad(decorate);
</script>
```

Is there any better way to do this? Is there an alternative to `dojo.addOnLoad`? Can this be achieved through SSJS?

Comment: You can't do this by server side scripting. All the cool stuff are added on the client, so your only solution is to manipulate the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your passthrough tag inside the button:

```
<xp:button styleClass="btn" value="BUTTON">
   <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</xp:button>
```

The generated HTML will look like this:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2"><i class="icon-ok"></i>BUTTON</button>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use other HTML elements and add content inside, a *xp:panel* can help:

```
<xp:panel styleClass="btn" tagName="a">
   <i class="icon-ok"></i>
   ...OTHER INTERESTING THINGS INSIDE...
</xp:panel>
```

That's the resulting HTML code:

```
<a class="btn">
   <i class="icon-ok"></i>...OTHER INTERESTING THINGS INSIDE...</a>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know that I can nest plain html tags inside <xp> tags. And instead of using the `<i>` tags directly, I can do the following `<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" tagName="i" styleClass="icon-ok"></xp:text>`. And now I can programatically change style class, meaning I can change the look of the button without a problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @SasaBrkic: You can always nest components (a html tag is nothing else than a passthrough component). But the rendering can result in different HTML code. If you nest two xp:text components, the rendered elements will not be nested.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.squareone.ba/2013/05/xpages-twitter-bootstrap-and-button.html) to illustrate this technique. There is also a demo application where you can [see it in action](http://web1.cs-computing.com/apps/demo/bootstrap/bootstrap_demo.nsf/buttons.xsp).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use **button**? if you want, here is an alternative, try using anchor
 like this `<a href='#' class='btn'><i class='icon-ok'></i> Approve </a>`

Comment: I do tend to use `<a>` styled as button. Both approaches work fine when I am dealing with static values. But, as soon as I need to calculate something, be it class, value, target, or if I want to attach an event, I must use XPages core control. And then, I have the same problem - how to inject the `<i>` tag in the label of the link or button core control.
The most elegant solution would be if the label attribute could be set to be HTML, just like it can be done for Computed Fields. Then, we could easily inject the HTML using server-side computations.